# How to integrate maven multiple modules report into one

Tags: maven, module, report, maven-module

I have 10 folders each one hosts a respective project. the report plugin was added to pom.xml of each project, which is not convenient to check the report into each project, I'm wondering if there is a way to integrate all project reports into one?

Answer (score 0):

You can create another Maven project and make those 10 projects as modules of it. Then add the report section into this new project, with this, the existing 10 projects don't need any report config any more. Like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project  ...>
    ...
    <modules>
        <module>project-a</module>
            <module>project-b</module>
            ...
            <module>project-z</module>
    </modules>
    ...
    <reporting>
        <plugins>
        ...
        </plugins>
    </reporting>
</project>
```

Comment: I did the same, no any html but some css files and pictures generated

Comment: @user2002518 What plugins are you actually using ?